Is epiphenomenalism really a form of property dualism?
Specifically referring here to supervenience, such that X supervenes on Y if change in X entails logically a change in Y.
Unless I'm mistaken, property dualism tries to argue that mental states are not reducible to, nor supervene on physical states.
Doesn't epiphenomenalism hold though that a change in the mental entails logically a change in the physical, since nothing else can cause a change in the mental?

Property dualism holds that "there are two essentially different kinds of property out in the world", it does not say anything about supervenience. And epiphenomenalism holds that physical causes mental and mental does not cause physical, it says nothing about mental causing mental or changing without a cause. Mental is often described as "spontaneous" after all.
